# OSX - NSButton: set inset of checkbox to title label

Tags: macos, checkbox, spacing, nsbutton

I've got an NSButton as a checkbox, and I'd like to set the inset to the title label.
[image: Instead of this...]

[image: Something like this]

Any ideas? 
In iOS, it can be set via the IB, in OSX apparently not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly there is nothing in IB for that. So you should do it in the code:

```
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 20.0

    checkButton.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: checkButton.title, attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle])
```

Here is how it looks then:

[image]